# How can I bind public ip to docker

Tags: networking, docker

I want to crawl a website, but it will ban my spider if the crawler sends too many http requests at a short time.I want to crawl it using differnt ips at the same time, just like distributed crawler.I have some public staic ips,but i have only one centos7 server.So I want to use docker containers to bind my public ips on my server. What should I do to bind public ip to docker containers?I can't solve my problem by reading the official document[enter link description here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) .I hope someone can answer me as detailed as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: It depends of your network topology. Maybe you can do static routes on containers. To do that, there must be different possible gateways. Hard to know without more info. Are you behind a router? Has the same router all the possible static ips? or do you have different input/output internet gateways?

Comment: Almostly, there are two gateways.One is used for local network, while another is used for public network for the requests in and out.I am not familiar with the computer network.I hope you can understand what i said and give me a reply.Thanks.

Comment: I guess if all of your ip publics are used by the same gateway you can't do that. Do you have control of that gateway?

Comment: I don't have the control

Comment: In that case I think you can't. Let's see if anybody have another answer.